# Difference in method accessibility of class and interface methods in Java

Tags: java, interface

Why does class ref type and interface ref type have a different access scope of their methods.

In the following example

```
interface ImInterface{

   void do1();

   void do2();

}


class MyClass implements ImInterface {

   void do1(){
   System.out.println("do1");
   }

   void do2(){
    System.out.println("do2");
   }

   void do3(){
    System.out.println("do3");
   }
}
```

Could you help me understand why `mc` variable defined like

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
```

cannot access `do1 and d2` without any cast? It implements all functionality from contract (`ImInterface`). Why is it like this in Java?

Also, why `mi` defined like

```
MyInterface mi = new MyClass();
```

cannot access `do3` without any cast?

I know both `mi` and `mc` have different types, but after implementations both become one now, then why it's a difference to access without cast? `mc` and `mi` both point to same type of instance.

Comment: add public modifier to do1 and do2

Comment: Interfaces declare methods that MUST be declared public in implementing classes;  In fact, I can’t see how your code would even compile with MyClass having do1 and do2 being not public.

Comment: Guys dont go with a syntax errors, please consider the scenario. :)

Comment: @Maria if you don't provide more context like where you declared the `mi` and `mc` objects it's normal for people to focus on the "syntax". Declaring the methods with package visibility and accessing them outside of the package might be the reason why you aren't able to access them.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are declaring the object `mi` as of type `MyInterface`, you will only have access to the methods that are declared on `MyInterface`.

When you declare the object `mc` as of type `MyClass`, you will have access to all the methods declared in `MyClass` and its superclass.

When Java looks at the reference `mi`, it will just know that it is of type `MyInterface`.

Now if you declared `mc` outside of the package then you won't be able to access any of their methods because they have package visibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Why mc cannot access do1 and d2 without any cast ?

It can, provided you call `mc.do1()` or `mc.do2()` from a class within the same package where MyClass is declared. In Java, when you don't declare an access modifier for a method or a field, Java allows it to be accessible only within the same 'package' where the class is declared. For do1() and do2() to be accessible anywhere, declare them with a public 'modifier':

```
public void do1() {
   ...
}
```

Note: This is not applicable for interfaces as all methods in interfaces are by default 'public', even when the keyword is not specified.

> Why mi cannot access do3 without any cast ?

That's how Java is designed. An interface specifies a contract (*what*, and not, *how*). So when a class implements an interface, it has to adhere to that contract, plus it can declare it's own functionalities. But as long as you refer to the object of the implementation class with the reference of the interface:

`MyInterface mi = new MyClass();`

the interface reference will be able to access only the method it has declared. In other words, the interface reference can only tell what it 'knows for sure' to be present in the implementation (as the implementation class has implemented the interface) and not the other functionalities (methods) of the implementation class.

Answer (score 1):

Methods of an **interface** are implicitly *public* and methods of a **class** with no specified access modifier have **weaker access privileges than public**.

When you implement an interface's method, the implementing class cannot have weaker access modifier for it than specified in the interface.

In your example you are trying to implement an interface with implicitly public methods through methods that have *no modifier*, violating the rule above. If you want to make this code work, you should make these methods explicitly public.

`mi` cannot access `do3()` because it has no information about this method in `ImInterface` declaration (and `mi`s type is `ImInterface`). This is the reason you have to explicitly cast `mi` to `MyClass`, telling Java that it can treat this object in by more "narrow" means.

You can find more information about interfaces [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).